# Page is not responding after using mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

Hey I have to change page Jquery Mobile. I am using following code :

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#home", {
    changeHash: false,
    reload: true
});
```

Page is changing but click event is not working. You can say page is not responding. If I reload page then it is responding.
NOTE : I am using chrome browser. And I have to reload the page forcefully that is why I am using   "reload: true"

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What click event? How and when are you binding the click event?

Comment: try binding your click events to the document instead of class or id, If you haven't done so already. e.g ($(document).on("click", ".class  or #id", function() { });)

Comment: Thanks guys it is working with @Tasos suggestions. I was using $("#home").on("click", ".subjects", function(e){) . My bad !!! you guys rocks. :)